# Amazon Analytics Datamining for sellers

Tags: web-scraping, analytics, data-mining, amazonsellercentral

How do tools like Helium10(H10) or JungleScout(JS) work? They pull data from amazon, make it user friendly and sell it to Sellers.  I'd be lost without it.  But what are its limitations - is it real time? How is it working. Can anyone get this information on their own?  Why wouldn't amazon gate/block us from getting it - then SELL it on their own?  I am wondering lots of things....  H10/JS "help" videos never get into what is actually going on and in some cases it seems a bit "guarded".  I heard one person say: H10/JS create their own databases & mirror them off some information amazon made public years ago (so it is all 'best guesses'?)  I don't get it!

I use and depend on these tools.  But what is a good place to learn how they work?  I'd like to spend an hour a week reading for the next 10 yrs.  Not to design my own, they are too inexpensive, no need for that.  I would just like to be more informed - it is amazing whatever is going on.  What keywords should I use - Where should I start.  If this is the wrong place to ask where do I go to ask.  (How do I better ask this question)